# NSString componentsSeparatedByString: 1024 characters long

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsstring

I'm trying to separate an array of JSON objects using componentsSeparatedByString and the resulting array string contain only 1024 chars of the splited sections. Each resulted substring only gets to 1024 chars. The rest is truncated out.

```
objectsJSONStrings = datastr?.componentsSeparatedByString(separator)
```

Is there a length limitation?

Comment: Probably the *debugger* shows only a truncated part of the strings.

Comment: `println(objectsJSONStrings.length)`